# Pass URL as parameter in silex controller

Tags: php, url, silex

I want to pass a url as parameter to a controller as like below:

```
$api->get('/getfile/{fileurl}', function(Request $request, $fileurl){
              //do something
}
```

Here {fileurl} can be a valid http url. However, the above mapping isn't working and resulting 404(may be because of the slashes in the {fileurl} part?) . How to solve it to accept the $url in $fileurl variable?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the regex matching the fileurl part match slashes, as it does not do that by default.

Simply do an `assert("fileurl", ".*")` call on your route like this:

```
$app->get("/getfile/{fileurl}", function ($fileurl) use ($app) {
    // ...
})->assert("fileurl", ".*");
```

Make sure it's your last parameter, as it'll swallow everything.

Answer (score 1):

Use base64_encode() before passing the $fileurl

```
$fileurl = base64_encode(YOUR_URL);
```

and decode $fileurl in your controller:

```
$app->get("/getfile/{fileurl}", function ($fileurl) use ($app) {
  $decoded_fileurl = base64_decode($fileurl);
  // ..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

why not?

```
$app->get("/getfile/{fileurl}", function ($fileurl) use ($app) {
  $decoded_fileurl = urldecode($fileurl);
  // ..
});
```

`urldecode()` was meant for exactly this purpose, you just need to make sure to encode the url before creating the link in twig it's as simple as `{{ myvar|e('url') }}` or in php `urlencode($myvar)` I was just trying to pass around email addresses in urls and ran into the same problem. I post it here for posterity.